# Enumerate rows by category

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, running-count

Enumerate values rows by category

I have the following dataframe that I'm ordering by category and values:

```py
d = {"cat":["a","b","a","c","c"],"val" :[1,2,3,1,4]  }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.sort_values(["cat","val"])
```

[image]

Now from that dataframe I want to enumarate the occurrence of each category
so the result is as follows:

```py
df["cat_count"] = [1,2,1,1,2]
```

[image]

Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Your output might be incorrect? Seems like your row order changed... Either way I'm guessing `df.groupby('cat').cumcount()+1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use cumcount like this. Details here [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('cat').cumcount()+1
print (df)
```

Output

```
  cat  val  count
0   a    1      1
2   a    3      2
1   b    2      1
3   c    1      1
4   c    4      2
```